# Oracle SQL - How to return common date periods and "divide" when there are gaps between periods

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to return common date periods (per id) from below data, but I cannot find a way to handle case when date periods have a gap between common periods. Can anyone help?

```
|id|code_id|code|date_from|date_to|
|--|--|--|--|--|
|10|100|    1000    |02/02/2022             |03/02/2022 23:57:00|
|10|100|    1000    |07/02/2022 01:00:00    |08/02/2022         |
|10|100|    2000    |02/02/2022             |02/02/2022 23:00:00|
|10|100|    2000    |07/02/2022 03:00:00    |08/02/2022         |
|10|200|    2000    |02/02/2022 02:14:00    |04/02/2022 21:37:00|
|20|100|    1000    |01/02/2022 05:00:00    |03/02/2022         |
|30|100|    2000    |02/02/2022             |02/02/2022 23:00:00|
|30|200|    2000    |02/02/2022 02:14:00    |04/02/2022         |
|40|100|    2000    |07/02/2022 03:00:00    |08/02/2022 23:10:00|
|50|200|    2000    |04/02/2022             |04/02/2022 21:37:00|
|50|200|    3000    |04/02/2022 02:12:00    |05/02/2022 23:31:00|
```

Below simple query works fine, but only for ids which have one common period (with no gaps).

I would expect for **id = 10** to return two rows (as there is a gap between dates) for periods which are:

I) *02/02/2022 00:00:00* <-> *04/02/2022 21:37:00*

II) *07/02/2022 01:00:00* <-> *08/02/2022 00:00:00*

```
 SELECT id
       ,MIN(date_from) date_from
       ,MAX(date_to)   date_to
  FROM my_gtt 
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY id
```

Current results (but id = 10 is incorrect):

```
|id|date_from|date_to|
|--|--|--|
|10|    02/02/2022          |08/02/2022         |
|20|    01/02/2022 05:00:00 |03/02/2022         |
|30|    02/02/2022          |04/02/2022         |
|40|    07/02/2022 03:00:00 |08/02/2022 23:10:00|
|50|    04/02/2022          |05/02/2022 23:31:00|
```

Data and table creation:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_gtt
(
  id         NUMBER(10),
  code_id    NUMBER(10),
  code       NUMBER(10),
  date_from  DATE,
  date_to    DATE
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 100, 1000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), TO_DATE('03-02-2022 23:57:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 100, 1000, TO_DATE('07-02-2022 01:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('08-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 100, 2000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), TO_DATE('02-02-2022 23:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 100, 2000, TO_DATE('07-02-2022 03:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('08-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 200, 2000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022 02:14:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('04-02-2022 21:37:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (20, 100, 1000, TO_DATE('01-02-2022 05:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('03-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (30, 100, 2000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), TO_DATE('02-02-2022 23:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (30, 200, 2000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022 02:14:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('04-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (40, 100, 2000, TO_DATE('07-02-2022 03:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('08-02-2022 23:10:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (50, 200, 2000, TO_DATE('04-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), TO_DATE('04-02-2022 21:37:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (50, 200, 3000, TO_DATE('04-02-2022 02:12:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('05-02-2022 23:31:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` is the simplest solution:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_gtt
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY date_from, date_to
  MEASURES
    MIN(date_from) AS start_date,
    MAX(date_to)   AS end_date
  PATTERN (overlap* last_row)
  DEFINE
    overlap AS MAX(date_to) >= NEXT(date_from)
);
```

However, if you are on an earlier version you can find the output using:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MIN(dt) AS date_from,
       MAX(dt) AS date_to
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt, ROWNUM) AS match_no
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           dt,
           type * SUM(type) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt, ROWNUM) AS value
    FROM   my_gtt
    UNPIVOT (dt FOR type IN (date_from AS 1, date_to AS -1))
  )
  WHERE  value IN (1,0)
)
GROUP BY id, match_no
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 100, 1000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), TO_DATE('03-02-2022 23:57:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 100, 1000, TO_DATE('07-02-2022 01:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('08-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 100, 2000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), TO_DATE('02-02-2022 23:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 100, 2000, TO_DATE('07-02-2022 03:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('08-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (10, 200, 2000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022 02:14:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('04-02-2022 21:37:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (20, 100, 1000, TO_DATE('01-02-2022 05:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('03-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (30, 100, 2000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), TO_DATE('02-02-2022 23:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (30, 200, 2000, TO_DATE('02-02-2022 02:14:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('04-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (40, 100, 2000, TO_DATE('07-02-2022 03:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('08-02-2022 23:10:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (50, 200, 2000, TO_DATE('04-02-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), TO_DATE('04-02-2022 21:37:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (50, 200, 3000, TO_DATE('04-02-2022 02:12:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), TO_DATE('05-02-2022 23:31:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (60, 200, 3000, DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-10');
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (60, 200, 3000, DATE '2022-01-02', DATE '2022-01-04');
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (60, 200, 3000, DATE '2022-01-06', DATE '2022-01-11');
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (60, 200, 3000, DATE '2022-01-13', DATE '2022-01-16');
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES (60, 200, 3000, DATE '2022-01-14', DATE '2022-01-15');
```

Both output:

> | ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | 2022-02-04 21:37:00 |
> | 10 | 2022-02-07 01:00:00 | 2022-02-08 00:00:00 |
> | 20 | 2022-02-01 05:00:00 | 2022-02-03 00:00:00 |
> | 30 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | 2022-02-04 00:00:00 |
> | 40 | 2022-02-07 03:00:00 | 2022-02-08 23:10:00 |
> | 50 | 2022-02-04 00:00:00 | 2022-02-05 23:31:00 |
> | 60 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-11 00:00:00 |
> | 60 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=507a2716412168ead8c9559b3de007a0)*

Comment: Is there a way to return also eg. max(code_id) from above query? 
So output would have 4 columns: id, code_id, start_date and end_date

Comment: @MichalAndrzej Yes, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=62d84b22e51c4111af8dd72e6822b80e)

Answer (score 1):

SQL pattern matching can help:

```
select * from my_gtt match_recognize (
  partition by id
  order by date_from, date_to
  measures 
    min ( date_from ) start_date,
    max ( date_to ) end_date
  pattern ( overlap* gap )
  define 
    overlap as next ( date_from ) <= max ( date_to )
);

        ID START_DATE           END_DATE            
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 02-FEB-2022 00:00:00 04-FEB-2022 21:37:00
        10 07-FEB-2022 01:00:00 08-FEB-2022 00:00:00
        20 01-FEB-2022 05:00:00 03-FEB-2022 00:00:00
        30 02-FEB-2022 00:00:00 04-FEB-2022 00:00:00
        40 07-FEB-2022 03:00:00 08-FEB-2022 23:10:00
        50 04-FEB-2022 00:00:00 05-FEB-2022 23:31:00
```

I discuss how this works in more detail in [pattern matching use cases](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/ogb-appreciation-day-sql-pattern-matching-match_recognize-use-cases)

Comment: The `pattern` and `define` conditions do not always match overlaps. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1736b5ad5ca5ef65916079995f31b61e) should have 2 rows for the `id` 60 but this gives 3 rows and the start/end dates are not correct.

Comment: Good catch; I've fixed it